# Compile C++ error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
constexpr double euro_to_dollar = 1.11;
constexpr double yen_to_dollar = 0.0081;
double dollar = 1.00;

char unit= 'A';
cout <"Please enter a value followed by e or y: \n";
cin >>dollar>> unit;
if (unit= 'e')
cout << dollar << "Euro == " << euro_to_dollar*dollar << "dollar\n";
else if (unit='y')
        cout << dollar << "Yen== " << yen_to_dollar * dollar << "dollar\n";
}
```

```
5   error: 'constexpr' was not declared in this scope  
5   error: expected ';' before 'double'  
7   error: expected ';' before 'double'  
15  error: 'euro_to_dollar' was not declared in this scope

17  error: 'yen_to_dollar' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm doing a problem from Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ (2nd Edition)by Bjarne Stroustrup. And I can see what I'm doing wrong here. I am a trying to learn C++, so I am basically a beginner.  I appreciate the help guys.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Does it support C++11?

Comment: `cout <"Please enter a value followed by e or y: \n";` should be `cout <<`

Answer (score 1):

The `constexpr` keyword was introduced in C++11, compile with `-std=c++11`. 
Example:

with g++: `g++ main.cpp -o program.exe -std=c++11`

with code::blocks: 
Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler Settings -> Compiler Flags -> tick the box `Have g++ follow the C++ ISO C++ language standard` -> Ok

---

You are also assigning to a variable in your if statements, replace with `==`:

```
if (unit= 'e')
    //  ^
```

and

```
else if (unit='y')
        //   ^
```

And you're missing a `<` in your call to std::cout:

```
cout <"Please enter a value followed by e or y: \n";
 //  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is there in your local header file

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
```

In place of that I added following lines of code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
```

`if (unit = 'e')`//doing assignment
 should correct to as follows

if (unit == 'e'), //checking equal or not

`else if (unit ='y')` should correct to as follows because of same reason

```
else if (unit =='y')
```

Moreover you should compile using compiler option `-std=c++11`